# CSS class styling common general grouping vs specific grouping

Tags: css

*My question is: if i want to add any common property to all images then can i just use grid-wrapper class? why to use img element to style image when every image is under grid-wrapper class and i want  to set common properties to all images?*

**Please clarify.**

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">

<div class="box zone"><img src="pic03.jpg"></div>
<div class="box zone"><img src="pic01.jpg"></div>
<div class="box zone"><img src="pic02.jpg"></div>
<div class="box zone"><img src="pic04.jpg"></div>
<div class="box zone"><img src="pic05.jpg"></div>

</div>


.grid-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(350px,1fr));
}
```

Comment: because this is how CSS is designed .. you target an element to apply a style to it, we don't add style to one element that will be applied to another.

Answer (score 0):

you can select elements with the same parent in css and apply style to them and there's no need to add additional classed to them. in the case of the code you have provided:
`.grid-wrapper img {}` or `.grid-wrapper > .box.zone > img {}`. if this isn't the answer you're looking for please clarify your question so I can help you.